# Imput the txt dataset and remove the na in R

Tags: r

the txt files dataset is like 108.898;115.437;NA;115.879;111.473;NA;114.949;109.894;NA;

Just some number and NA, and is just one row

The goal is to load the dataset and remove the NA transfer to a vector c();

```
x = read.table("abc.txt",sep = ";")
```

is the code that I used to load the data, but there is no such code as "rm.na", and I tried `na.omit()` and `complete.cases()`, but these two codes will just remove all the values since this dataset is only one row.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a single row, use `scan`

```
na.omit(scan('abc.txt', sep = ";", what = numeric(), quiet = TRUE))
[1] 108.898 115.437 115.879 111.473 114.949 109.894
```